# While downloading freeglut, cannot find -lopengl32, -lgdi32, and -lwinmm

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I am trying to install [freeglut](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/freeglut). I have a 64-bit system and I mounted Linux on my Windows using [Wubi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi) for 64-bit.

When I download freeglut it says:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopengl32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdi32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwinmm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libglut.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/johndrake/Downloads/freeglut-2.8.1/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/johndrake/Downloads/freeglut-2.8.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
johndrake@ubuntu:~/Downloads/freeglut-2.8.1$ ^Cke install
johndrake@ubuntu:~/Downloads/freeglut-2.8.1$
```

---

```
libs/libglut_la-freeglut_teapot.o .libs/libglut_la-freeglut_videoresize.o .libs/libglut_la-freeglut_window.o .libs/libglut_la-freeglut_xinput.o -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -lm -lrt -O2 -Wl,-soname -Wl,libglut.so.0 -o .libs/libglut.so.0.0.0

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopengl32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdi32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwinmm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libglut.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/johndrake/Downloads/freeglut-2.8.1/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1 johndrake@ubuntu:~/Downloads/freeglut-2.8.1$
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: here is more code.libs/libglut_la-freeglut_teapot.o .libs/libglut_la-freeglut_videoresize.o .libs/libglut_la-freeglut_window.o .libs/libglut_la-freeglut_xinput.o   -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -lm -lrt  -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libglut.so.0 -o .libs/libglut.so.0.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopengl32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdi32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwinmm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libglut.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/johndrake/Downloads/freeglut-2.8.1/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
johndrake@ubuntu:~/Downloads/freeglut-2.8.1$

Answer (score 1):

Why not just install `freeglut3` from the repositories? In the same terminal you are right now, type this:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3
```

It will ask you for your password, enter your password and done.